# Error: Unable to resolve module ... could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

**Error:** Unable to resolve module navigation/stack-routes from /Users/jacksaunders/gymzoo/src/navigation/tabs/MainTabs.tsx: navigation/stack-routes could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules

Hello there! I have just tried to set up absolute imports (using navigation/stack instead of ../../../navigation/stack)

I am not sure what is happening because it looks to be okay in my IDE but my metro is flagging the following error.

[image: error]

Here is my tsconfig for context:

[image: tsconfig]

I have tried deleting my node modules, npm i and pod install but theres no luck.

Please throw your suggestions at me! Or advise me on how to solve this.

All the best,
Jack :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your `babel.config.js` to understand the root imports you're using here, because your `.tsconfig` only takes care about the code before it's transcompiled.

You can use the `babel-plugin-root-import` to achieve this.
npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-root-import

Example `babel.config.js` could look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
        [
            'babel-plugin-root-import',
            {
                paths: [
                    {
                        rootPathSuffix: './src',
                        rootPathPrefix: 'src',
                    },
                    {
                        rootPathSuffix: './src/navigation',
                        rootPathPrefix: 'navigation',
                    },
                ]
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

It's not an only option though, you can also use `babel-plugin-module-resolver`, which is more popular (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver).